# How to create underline tag with some custom attributes initially in ckeditor 5?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor-5 ,In that we r taking basic styles attributes as default and now I have to  add some custom attributes inside the element of an 'u' tag for tooltip purpose..
I Need Like

```
<u data-cid="458">some content</u>
```

But I got like

```
<u>some content</u>
```

And This is My code For underline in ckeditor

```
editor.conversion.attributeToElement({
            model: UNDERLINE,
            view: {
                name: 'u',
                styles: {
                    'text-decoration': 'underline dotted',
                    'color': 'red'
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define all the attributes under "config" like this:

```
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="{ toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strikethrough', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', '|', 'indentBlock' ] }" formControlName="noteText" data="Write...." (ready)="onReady($event)">
  </ckeditor>
```

Comment: I'm customizing the ckeditor , I need <u data="859" > content</u> like this